# jQuery Validate - Text input keeps clearing itself

Tags: jquery, textbox, jquery-validate

If the checkbox is unchecked and the textbox is empty then I need the validation message to pop up. It does pop up but deletes the text as it is entered keeping it as invalid. How do I make it so the validation disappears when the first character is typed and doesn't reappear unless the textbox is blank?

```
<form  id="practiceForm">
    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="textbox"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="active" id="checkbox"/>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#checkbox').attr('checked', true);

    if($('#checkbox').attr('checked')){
        $('#textbox').attr('disabled', true);
        $('#textbox').val('');
    } else {
        $('#textbox').attr('disabled', false);
    };


$('#checkbox').change(function () {
    if($('#checkbox').attr('checked')){
        $('#textbox').attr('disabled', true);
        $('#textbox').val('');
    } else {
        $('#textbox').attr('disabled', false);
    };
});

$.validator.addMethod("textValidate", function(value){
    if(!$('#checkbox').attr('checked')){
        if(!$('#textbox').val('') || !$('#textbox').val(null)){

            return true;
        };
    };  
}, "If box is not checked then there must be text"
);


$('#practiceForm').validate({
    rules: {
        //textValidate: true
        firstName:{ 
                    textValidate: true
                    }
                }
            });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This logic inside your `textValidate` method is broken:

```
if(!$('#textbox').val('') || !$('#textbox').val(null)){
```

Instead of checking for a `value` of `''` or `null`, you were *setting* that as the `value`.  Since the method is called on every key-up event, it was wiping out the input as you typed.

Try this instead:

```
$.validator.addMethod("textValidate", function (value) {
    if (!$('#checkbox').attr('checked')) {
        if (!$('#textbox').val() == '' || !$('#textbox').val() == null) {
             return true;
        };
    };
}, "If box is not checked then there must be text");
```

**Working Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/s2AjA/**

**Side issue:**

You don't need most of this code...

```
$('#checkbox').attr('checked', true);

if($('#checkbox').attr('checked')){
    $('#textbox').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#textbox').val('');
} else {
    $('#textbox').attr('disabled', false);
};
```

It's only run once on DOM ready and since you set `#checkbox` as `checked`, the `if/then` conditional that looks as the `checked` property is totally superfluous & unnecessary.

It can be more simply written as the following.  Also changed out `attr` with [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) which is technically more correct than `attr` when using jQuery 1.6+.

```
$('#checkbox').prop('checked', true);
$('#textbox').prop('disabled', true);
$('#textbox').val('');
```

Comment: Is that across the board? Is there a reason to use attr?

Comment: @user1795787, not "across the board".  See [this page](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) where `checked` is actually used in the real examples.  Quote: _"Properties generally affect the dynamic state of a DOM element without changing the serialized HTML attribute. Examples include the `value` property of input elements, the `disabled` property of inputs and buttons, or the `checked` property of a checkbox. The `.prop()` method **should be** used to set `disabled` and `checked` instead of the `.attr()` method."_

Comment: Thank you. That is a big help. When you are new at this it is tough to keep it all straight.

Comment: Thanks @Sparky I came across this same mistake and this helped me tremendously!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!$('#textbox').val('') || !$('#textbox').val(null)){
```

is setting the value of `#textbox` to "" and then null, and is making that if statement always return false.

You probably meant something like this:

```
if ($('#textbox').val() != '' || $('#textbox').val() != null) {
```